# php system() does not return the last line of output

Tags: php, python, exec, system, youtube-dl

I have a script that runs youtube-dl . I run that through a php file using system() like so:

```
$output = system(getenv("YOUTUBEDL_EXE") . " --no-color -f \"mp4\" \"5uR4JucaZ5I\" -o \"/tmp/%(id)s-%(format)s.%(ext)s\"",  $retVal);
```

The id of the video is not correct (on purpose) and the output I get when I run it on my terminal (linux) is this:

```
[youtube] 5uR4JucaZ5I: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 5uR4JucaZ5I: Downloading video info webpage
ERROR: 5uR4JucaZ5I: YouTube said: This video does not exist.
```

BUT, when I run it through system, the $output variable returns the second line, not the last one

```
[youtube] 5uR4JucaZ5I: Downloading video info webpage
```

I still get proper exit codes (that it is not completed successfully) but cannot get the last line with the ERROR: tag so I can parse the error. Unfortunately this is the only way to get the error as it only returns **1** on any error type.

(youtube-dl is written in python and its executable starts with :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and a zip header (PK ....) )

Any pointers in how to get the last line are massively welcomed!

Thanks

Comment: Well, it's an error, I'm not sure if that gets to `STDOUT`. Might just go straight to `STDERR`.

Comment: Thank you SO much!! Added a 2>&1 at the end of my command for redirecting STDERR and it works like a charm!

Comment: Of course!  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line is an error and gets written to `STDERR` and not `STDOUT`. You need to redirect the `STDERR` to `STDOUT` if you want to get errors with PHP, you can do that by adding `2>&1` at the end of your command.